# Get LobHelper from a UserType context

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-4.x, usertype

I'm migrating old Hibernate 2.x code to 4.x. One of the classes is a UserType between byte[] and Blob, and the code does something like this:

```
public void nullSafeSet(...) {
    ...
    Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(bytes);
    ...
}
```

In Hibernate 4.x, `Hibernate.createBlob` doesn't exist anymore, so I need to use `session.getLobHelper().createBlob(bytes)`, but I don't know how to get a LobHelper from a Session since I don't have a `Session`, only a `SessionImplementor`:

```
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor implementor) { ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out about the `ContextualLobCreator(LobCreationContext)` class, and that `SessionImplementor` implements `LobCreationContext`, so I basically converted

```
Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob((byte[]) value);
```

to

```
Blob blob = new ContextualLobCreator(implementor).createBlob((byte[]) value);
```